# How to create a Category by custom field(uid)?

Tags: api, django-oscar

cant change pk to uid, due to migration, so
My try:

```
class MyCategoryAdminDetail(CategoryAdminDetail, CreateAPIView):
lookup_field = 'uid'
```

"put" and "head" work correctly, but "create" creates categories always at the root, how can I fix this? 5 hours trying to understand what exactly is responsible for this in the Oscar, but did not understand